# Configure Log4Net to move rolled log files to different directory

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, rollingfileappender

How should I configure Log4Net to logroll daily and moved the rolled log files to a different directory?

Comment: I'd love to find out, too, but I'm not too hopeful: we're using nightly scripts for that :)

Comment: I had to write my own appender for this using the answer linked to the question.